# How to get an onclick listener to work with python flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I currently have a piece of Python Flask code that is very annoyingly not working.  On the Python side, I have

```
# Delete a project with the given ID from the system
# Must also delete the project from all user's owned and joined arrays
@app.route('/delete_project/<string:project_id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@require_user_login
def delete_project(project_id):
    # delete the project itself from the projects database
    mongo.db.projects.delete_one({'_id': ObjectId(project_id)})

    # remove pointers to the project from the owner
    # as well as all collaborators
    mongo.db.sites.update(
    { },
    { '$pull': { 'owned_projects': ObjectId(project_id) , 'joined_projects': ObjectId(project_id) } }
    )

    # TODO: delete all files associated with this project
    # also delete all JSON objects associated with the files

    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

On the HTML side, the code looks like this

```
    <button id="{{project['_id']|string}}" class="btn btn-info">
        <a href="">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete Project
        </a>
    </button>

    <script>

    document.getElementById("{{project['_id']|string}}").addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this project?")) {
            alert("{{ url_for('delete_project', project_id=project['_id']|string) }}");
            document.location.href("{{ url_for('delete_project', project_id=project['_id']|string) }}");
        }
    });
    </script>
```

When I click on this button, nothing happens.  The page merely refreshes, but no deletion occurs, and it appears that the site doesn't even hit the delete_project function at all.  Now, what is interesting is, if I put the code directly in the link, i.e.

```
    <button id="{{project['_id']|string}}" class="btn btn-info">
        <a href="{{ url_for('delete_project', project_id=project['_id']|string) }}">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete Project
        </a>
    </button>
```

The above code works, but doesn't have the needed confirmation popup.  The following also works, technically

```
    <button id="{{project['_id']|string}}" class="btn btn-info">
        <a href="">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete Project
        </a>
    </button>

    <script>

    document.getElementById("{{project['_id']|string}}").addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this project?")) {
            window.open("{{ url_for('delete_project', project_id=project['_id']|string) }}");
        }
    });
    </script>
```

BUT, it opens a new tab every time the button is pushed.  Doing `window.open('url', '_self')` has the same problem as location, i.e. it just refreshes the page without going anywhere.  I've tried `window.location`, `window.location.href`, `window.location.redirect`, and a bunch of other stuff besides, and nothing seems to actually work!

In an effort to see if it's redirecting AT ALL, I tried redirecting to a known good site, so I tried `window.location.href='htttps://www.google.com/'` to see if it'll go to Google.  Nope - nothing except for `window.open` seems to work at all.

Please help!  If I must use `window.open`, how can I make it work without opening a million new tabs?  And why doesn't `window.location` work?!  I'm pulling my hair out here...!

Answer (score 0):

First, when you want to handle click in JS, you want to avoid  link to make transition (to href="", which simple reloads page) Use preventDefault on event

```
addEventListener('click', ev => { 
  ev.preventDefault();
  // do your handling here
})
```

To trigger delete from JS, window.open is not good options
Look at XHR request / fetch api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

in your case

```
fetch("{{ url_for('delete_project', project_id=project['_id']|string) }}");
```

As next step, it would be better use POST method instead of GET for delete request

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  It was a syntactical issue: `window.open` is coded as

```
window.open('your/url/here')
```

But window.location is coded as

```
window.location = 'your/url/here'
```

Thus the end result was that I was not calling proper javascript and it just failed silently.  God I miss complied code!

Answer (score 0):

fetch("{{ url_for('delete_project', project_id=project['_id']|string) }}");
As next step, it would be better use POST method instead of GET for delete request

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.